# Save base64 encoded image with jsf

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, cordova, base64

I'm using cordova/phonegap to capture image with device (currently iphone), the capturing is working fine, I get the base64 encoded image as a string in a callback:

```
    function handlePhotoSuccess(image){
        document.getElementById("uploadItemForm:picture").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + image;
        document.getElementById("uploadItemForm:imageBase64").value = image;
    }
```

The imageBase64 element is a hidden h:inputText.

The image show correctly, but the saved value in the bean is not correct. It has like the image's 30% and the other part is gray.

The value in the backing bean is a String, I convert it to a byte array, then save it:

```
    byte[] imageByte;
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    try {
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        temp.setContent(is); //temp will be saved to database

        images.put(currentAttribute.getId(), imageByte);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Maybe I do something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What package are you getting `BASE64Decoder` from?

Comment: `import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` The problem will be the length of the base64 string :/